# POST Request Body for query paginated data in elasticsearch AWS by filtering data on source fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I'm using this JSON for filtering my payments with paymentStatus.
I want to filter the ConfirmationPending payments with some searchText `x` and i have no idea where should i add `x` to get paginated filter payments.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "ConfirmationPending",
      "fields": ["paymentStatus"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In which field do you want to search for `x`?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple constraints by leveraging the `bool/must` query:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "paymentStatus": "ConfirmationPending"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "otherField": "x"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```